# create Tabbarbase Application in swift with two or more tabbar

Tags: swift

I am creating tabbar base application.. but i cant import second viewcontroller in to AppDelegate file like in Objective - C..can any one help me out..

I have tried to import like
import UIKit
import SecondVc.swift

but it will give me error : No such module like SecondVC.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can create the `TabBar` with two or more `viewController`.

I just take a mistake to create a new file in swift.

we have to create a new file with **cocoTouch Class** but I am creating with **Swift File**.

And yes we can not import a new ViewController like in Objective - C. We **have to make the object of those viewController**.

here, is my code of appDelegate file to create TabBar base Application in swift.

```
import UIKit<br>
@UIApplicationMain<br>
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    var tabbar = UITabBarController()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let HomeVC : ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC") as ViewController
    HomeVC.tabBarItem.title = "Home"
    HomeVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home.png")

    let SettingVC : SettingViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SettingVC") as SettingViewController
    SettingVC.tabBarItem.title = "Setting"
    SettingVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "settings.png")

    var arrayTabbar = [HomeVC,SettingVC]

    tabbar.viewControllers = arrayTabbar
    tabbar.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    window?.rootViewController = tabbar
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```